# What is the word for the hole/cup at the top of a knight's helmet from which a plume streams?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for the hole or cup at the top of a knight's helmet from which a plume streams?

Answer (score 1):

"Crest holder" or "crest support". See this: http://www.museumoflondonprints.com/image/78976/unknown-roman-helmet-crest-holder

Answer (score 0):

Crest block.  Go here:
[Roman helmet](http://www.larp.com/legioxx/crests.html)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, although this may not be the type of helmet originally in mind when the question was asked, Officers of the Household Cavalry in the UK wear a helmet with a plume similar to this:

[image: Helmet and plume of an officer of the Life Guards]

[Life Guards helmet and plume from [householdcavalry.info](http://householdcavalry.info/)]

The mount which supports the plume is called a **plume spike**.